# How to edit notification toolbar icon without affecting content icon

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've created a foreground service notification and now I am trying to update the toolbar icon without affecting the content icon of notication (showed when toolbar is expanded).

Here's the [example of desired behaviour](https://www.kapwing.com/videos/653bb508f6382c89c7187222) I am trying to achieve.

I tried doing this with an update call of new notification with a different small icon (`setSmallIcon()`) however this method changes both icons. The only way I found working was to set the small icon and then setting `setCustomContentView()`. However this approach seemed like too much of a workaround based on what I am trying to achieve, and raised some issues with mirroring of the original notifiction like:

1. the `setSmallIcon()` method changes the size of the notification to fit the display params. In custom layout I have to specify width and height of imageView and even tho I provide xml file as image the params won't be automatically adjusted.
2. The notification look may change on diffrent devices.

So **is there** a way to set the notification "content/extended toolbar" icon without the need of using `setCustomContentView()`. **If not**, what's the best way to mirror the original notification layout on each device?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Notification builder for reference:

```
private Notification createForegroundNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        final NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(this.getString(R.string.channel_name),
                NotificationChannel.class.getSimpleName(), NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        channel.enableLights(true);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, this.getString(R.string.channel_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_time)
            .setCustomContentView(new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.segment_notification))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .build();
}
```